# where can i get deep documentation of ArgoCD apis

Tags: argoproj, argocd

I need to list all applications based on some label filters.

https://argocd_domain/api/v1/applications

in order to list all apps from argoCD API, I want to put all possible filters.

Answer (score 7):

The Argo CD API is documented in its [Swagger document](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/assets/swagger.json).

Copy and paste that JSON to the [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/), and you'll get a nicely-formatted page describing the API. Here's the section for listing applications:

[image: Screenshot of Swagger Editor section for listing applications]

The [function to handle a list-applications request](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/0ee983fc3126fe7ecc21c0e50833c5a45d0395a0/server/application/application.go#L114) calls `ConvertSelectorToLabelsMap`. Reading [the implementation of that parsing function](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/9254095ca5cab3666d500ec67cd00f9ab0d113d7/pkg/labels/labels.go#L165), you can find the expected format of the `selector` parameter.

At a glance, it seems the format is a comma-delimited list of `key=value` pairs.

Using the Swagger Editor, I generated the this test URL:

```sh
curl -X GET "https://editor.swagger.io/api/v1/applications?selector=label1%3Dvalue1%2Clabel2%3Dvalue2" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

Looks like you'll need to URL-encode the equals signs and commas.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the Swagger docs by setting the path to /swagger-ui in your Argo CD server address. E.g. `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui`.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a hosted version of Argo's Swagger UI on https://cd.apps.argoproj.io/swagger-ui

[image: ArgoCD Swagger UI]